# Differenza tra mensolina e comodino (e piani rialzati)

Tags: word-meaning, word-usage, word-choice, etymology, single-words

Vorrei sapere (anche con delle immagini), che differenza vi è tra comodino e mensolina (e comò).

Lo chiedo perché in cucina vi è un piano rialzato (cosa, con un nome un po' troppo lungo da dire in quelle situazioni dove le conversazioni necessitano di parole brevi e veloci).

Dunque, che cos'è?

(Quello a sinistra nell'immagine è un tavolo)

[image: piano rialzato]

Comment: Probabilmente si tratta di un uso regionale, perché io non ho mai sentito *mensolina* e *comodino* lo userei solo per un mobile presente in camera da letto (quello che in inglese si chiama "bedstand"). L'oggetto sulla destra per me è un "ripiano" o, se dobbiamo riferici ai cassetti, una "credenza". Ma probabilmente li chiamerei "cassetti della cucina" e basta.

Comment: OP, ho aggiustato un po' il tuo italiano. (Usi troppe virgole! :) )

Comment: Hai visto le definizioni di [comodino](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/comodino1) e [comò](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/como)? Forse possono esserti d'aiuto.

Comment: "Ripiano" è una possibilità, ma più semplicemente io direi "piano", "piano della cucina", mi sembra la dizione più standard: "piano della cucina in marmo", "piano della cucina in legno".

Comment: Grazie per le risposte. Dunque, sia ripiano, che credenza, che piano della cucina (in marmo o in legno). Magari qualcuno può scrivere una risposta così la posso accettare, grazie.